# Why does not git-filter-branch get linked?

Tags: git, macos, github

I installed git on macOS 11.2.1, git version is 2.30.1, and I run `ls -lih` in `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.1/libexec/git-core`, and get this result

```
8081498 lrwxr-xr-x   1 devaccount  staff    13B Feb  9 07:20 git-fetch -> ../../bin/git
18081680 lrwxr-xr-x   1 devaccount  staff    13B Feb  9 07:20 git-fetch-pack -> ../../bin/git
18081665 -rwxr-xr-x   1 devaccount  staff    16K Feb  9 07:20 git-filter-branch
18081605 lrwxr-xr-x   1 devaccount  staff    13B Feb  9 07:20 git-fmt-merge-msg -> ../../bin/git
18081575 lrwxr-xr-x   1 devaccount  staff    13B Feb  9 07:20 git-for-each-ref -> ../../bin/git
18081641 lrwxr-xr-x   1 devaccount  staff    13B Feb  9 07:20 git-for-each-repo -> ../../bin/git
```

Why does not git-filter-branch get linked? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter-branch command is implemented as a shell script (that then runs lots of Git plumbing commands, plus stuff like `sed` and of course any filters you specify, to get its work done).  So the "binary"—a tiny 16K—is actually just the shell source with the `.sh` suffix removed.  (The Git repository for Git stores all of its shell scripts as `.sh` files.)

The fetch, fetch-pack, fmt-merge-message, and so on commands are all implemented as one single rather large binary.  This is just an artifact of the way Git is built, meant to save a bit of space in the distributions and at runtime (when one Git command's source wants to invoke `git rev-parse`, for instance, that's more or less just a subroutine call now—though in fact most of this is turned into something rather fancier).  But the dashed forms of the commands, `git-foo`, are traditionally also executable.  Some scripts may still run `git-commit` instead of `git commit`, for instance.

For a transition period, then, Git includes binaries named `git-foo` as well as the `git foo` that's built in to the one big all-encompassing binary.  This is all handled by the main Makefile: the commands that aren't all lib-ized like this are listed separately from those that are.  The ones that are separate are installed separately *in* the `git-core` directory, and the ones that are all turned into the one big lump get symbolic links installed in `git-core` in case someone is still trying to invoke them with the dashed form.